# perltidy formatting multilines

Tags: perl, code-formatting, perl-tidy

I'm trying to get `perltidy` to format an `if` statement like this:

```
if ($self->image eq $_->[1]
        and $self->extension eq $_->[2]
        and $self->location  eq $_->[3]
        and $self->modified  eq $_->[4]
        and $self->accessed  eq $_->[5]) {
```

but no matter what I try, it insists on formatting it like this:

```
if (    $self->image eq $_->[1]
    and $self->extension eq $_->[2]
    and $self->location  eq $_->[3]
    and $self->modified  eq $_->[4]
    and $self->accessed  eq $_->[5]) {
```

Also, is there any way to get the last line of this block:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO image VALUES(NULL, "
    . $dbh->quote($self->image) . ", "
    . $dbh->quote($self->extension) . ", "
    . $dbh->quote($self->location) . ","
    . $dbh->quote($self->modified) . ","
    . $dbh->quote($self->accessed)
    . ")");
```

to jump up to the previous line like the other lines:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO image VALUES(NULL, "
    . $dbh->quote($self->image) . ", "
    . $dbh->quote($self->extension) . ", "
    . $dbh->quote($self->location) . ","
    . $dbh->quote($self->modified) . ","
    . $dbh->quote($self->accessed) . ")");
```

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
perltidy -ce -et=4 -l=100 -pt=2 -msc=1 -bar -ci=0 reporter.pm
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much to offer on the 1st question, but with the 2nd, have you considered refactoring it to use placeholders?  It would probably format up better, automaticaly do the quoting for you and give you (and the users of your module) a healthy barrier against SQL injection problems.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO image VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute(
    $self->image,    $self->extension, $self->location,
    $self->modified, $self->accessed
);
```

---

I've also found format skipping:  -fs to protect a specific segment of code from perltidy.  I'd put an example here but the Site seems to do a hatchet job on it...